# SQLite query is hanging

Tags: sqlite

So I have a table called athletes which has five fields: athlete_ids, sport, gold, silver, bronze. From this table we create a view called most_played_sports which contains all sports that has more than 500 athletes. The task at hand is to find distinct pairs of sports (sport_1, sport_2) using the above view such that the medal count for sport_1 is strictly less than sport_2.

The query I tried is:

```
create view if not exists most_played_sports as select sport, sum(gold)+sum(silver)+sum(bronze) as medal_count from athletes
    group by sport
    having count(id) >= 500;

select distinct athletes.sport as sport_1, most_played_sports.sport as sport_2 
    from athletes cross join most_played_sports
    where sport_1 > sport_2 and 
    ((select medal_count from most_played_sports where sport=sport_1) < (select medal_count from most_played_sports where sport=sport_2));
```

The second query is returning some results but is hanging. Is there a better way to do this task than I what I tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self-join:

```
select mps.sport as sport_1, mps2.sport as sport_2
from most_played_sports mps join
     most_played_sports mps2
     on mps.medal_count < mps2.medal_count;
```

The question does not suggest any need to use the original table.